# coredata many to many relation with fetchedResultController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities A and B, and their relationship is many to many. The class of the entities are like:

A
NSSet *toB

B
NSSet *toA

Now I have an object of A and I can get all related B objects by using the "toB" set. Since I need to re-order the B objects, I have to use an array to contain all the B objects, and the problem is there would be thousands of Bs, and I am worried about the array would occupy to much memory. So I was wondering if I can use NSfetchedResultController to fetch all the related B objects. The question is how I should do this? By using sort of predicate to fetch? Thank you.

Comment: When executing an `NSFetchedRequest` you can provide predicates to filter the results, or you can set a `fetchLimit` on the request. `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed to be used in conjunction with a `UITableView`. Also, the system can handle arrays with much more than thousands of results. Have you actually tried your request to see if memory is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `B` as the entity for the fetched results controller. Add a sort descriptor.

To restrict your `B`s to one `A`'s `B`s, add a predicate such as this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%@ in toA", anAObject)
```

Comment: I used something like toB contain %@, anAobject and it works

Comment: That is impossible. `CONTAINS` (with an `S`) is a string expression keyword for `NSPredicate`s. You need the aggregate operations operator `IN`.

Comment: I used sth like:
NSPredicate *predicateWordHeader = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"toPlanDetail contains %@", self.planDetail];
[requestWordHeader setPredicate:predicateWordHeader];

and it worked...

Comment: Yours is in a way a workaround, but string queries are expensive and you are not really addressing the actual question. I recommend following my approach.